# Non XA transaction for multiple schema's on the same instance

Tags: oracle, hibernate, weblogic

Currently I am using Weblogic with Oracle.

I have one instance of Oracle DB and two legacy schemas so I use tow datasources.

To keep transactionality I use XA but from time to time there are HeuristicExceptions thrown causing some inconsistency on data level

Now because it is the same instance is not possible somehow not to use XA and define a datasource that has access to both schemas ?

In this way i will not use XA anymore and avoid having data inconsitency.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use dblink. It is overkill. And also this might not be related to XA. Best solution is to use tables from both schemas from a single datasource. Either prefix tables in your queries by schema name, or create synonyms in one schema pointing onto tables in the other schema.

It is only matter database privileges. No need to deal with XA nor dblinks.
One db user need to have grants to manipulate tables in both schemas.

PS: you can use distributed transactions on connections pointing into the same database. If you insist on it. But in your case, there no need for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect one schema and create a DBLink for the other to give access to the second. I think that transaction will work through both schema.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/ds_concepts004.htm

Comment: Maybe you don't need DBLink, just have a user with rights on the both schemas